# AppHarbor + RavenDB - EsentFileAccessDeniedException

Tags: ravendb, appharbor

I'm trying to get my application running in AppHarbor using a RavenDB instance.  I've updated my raven libs to build 888 and I'm still getting the error below.  I've also allowed file system write access but im still getting the same error.  Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

```
[EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use]
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 2739
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetInit(JET_INSTANCE& instance) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 131
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 205
```

Comment: You should send that to support@ravenhq.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that during app startup, my app was creating a data directory in the application root. I discovered that I had an old reference to RavenDB Embedded which was on longer being used in the project which was creating the unneeded data directory. Once I removed that reference and pushed, everything began working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use the AppHarbor web worker instance file storage for the RavenDB backing store? That's a bad idea, use the hosted [RavenHQ add-on instead](https://appharbor.com/addons/ravenhq).

The self-hosted RavenDB not working on AppHarbor is a [known problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/292545/esent-fails-to-determine-the-minimum-i-o-block-size).

Even if you get it to work, note that the worker filesystems are not persisted when you deploy new versions of your code or in case of worker instance failure.

Comment: Im getting this error with the RavenHQ add-on. Im not running my own store in AppHarbor.

Comment: Could you provide additional details on your configuration? If you are indeed hitting the RavenHQ instance, you should get in touch with them.